# Load any file type into matlab

Tags: file, matlab, user-interface, matlab-load

I have a matlab GUI....I'd like to load ANY file type(doc,txt,dat,xls) into matlab as a matrix through the GUI...I'd appreciate any help I can get!!

Comment: What might the files you wish to load contain ?

Comment: d file contain string headers and numbers e.g(No.of Cars(header)...1,4,5,6.....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DOC, XLS, DAT to txt

---

As you might have realised by now, .doc are not plain-text. AFAIK, Matlab doesn't have any method to natively read these files. Hence, i suggest you do the following:

- **.txt** go ahead and implement your GUI to read and intrepret Matrix-data from a .txt file.

  > You might want to refer this:
  >
  > http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html
- **.xls** USe the xlsread() function in MATLAB. Documentation below:

  > http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html
- **.doc** files, Save as .txt and use the above .txt loader you implemented already.
- **.dat** is not a standard extension several kinds of apps use .dat files and the internal format is different in all cases. (Post me a sample standard .dat file if U have one and i'll try and get back to you as to how to parse it in matlab.)

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: thanks for d reply....but ur solution is about saving a matrix in matlab to a text file.....my question is.....how do i load these files as matrices into matlab.

Comment: ohh my mistake. Corrected the link now. Good LUCK!!